# How to recieve files from a server in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, python-sockets

I Have made a python script, where you can send files to a remote server and receive them. I can send them to the server but can not seem to retrieve them back I've attached both server and client.py

Server.py

```
import socket   # Import socket module
import os
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('139.59.173.187', 8010)) # Binds port and IP address
s.listen(3)    #wait for client to join
c, addr = s.accept()
def RecvFile():
    print ("File is comming ....")

    file = c.recv(1024)     #recieves file name from client
    print(file)

    f = open(file,'wb')      #open that file or create one
    l = c.recv(4096)         #now recieves the contents of the file
    while (l):
        print ("Receiving...File Data")
        f.write(l)            #save input to file
        l = c.recv(4096)      #get again until done
    print("The file",file,"has been succesfully saved to the server\nConnection from:",addr)
    f.close()

def SendFile():
    file = c.recv(1024)
    print(file)
    with open(file,'rb') as f:
        c.sendall(f.read())
    print("File has been sent to the client:", addr)
    main()


def main():
    option = str(c.recv(1024), 'utf-8')
    print(option)

    if option[:1] == "R":
        SendFile()
    elif option[:2] == "S":
        RecvFile()

main()
s.close()
```

Client.py

```
import time
import socket
import sys
import urllib.request
#import paramiko
def login():
    a = 1
    while a == 1:
        global user
        user = input("Username:")
        passw = input("Password:")
        with open('User.txt') as f:
         for line in f.readlines():
             us, pw = line.strip().split("|", 1)
             if (user == us) and (passw == pw):
                 print("login Successful!")
                 a = a+1
                 main()
                 return

        print("Incorrect details, Try again!")



def register():
    print("You will recieve a generated Username from your Name and age")
    regName = input("First Name: ")
    regAge = input("Age: ")
    regPass = input("Password: ")
    regUser = (regName[0:3]+regAge)
    with open('User.txt', 'a') as file:

        file.writelines(regUser+"|"+regPass+"\n")
    print("You have Succesfully registered")
    print("Your Username is:"+regUser)
    print("Your Password is:"+regPass)
    print("!Please keep these credentials secure!")

def main():
    print("=========================Welcome to Bluetooth Projector=========================")
    option = input("Here are your options:\n--> Press C to connect to the projector\n--> Press F for File System")
    x = 1
    while x == 1:
        if option == "C" or option == "c":
            optionc(x)
        elif option == "F" or "f":
            File_System()

def optionc():
        print("Loading.....")
        time.sleep(2)

        print("Obtaining IP addres.....")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Connecting.....")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Connected")
        x = x+1


def File_System():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('139.59.173.187',8010))

    print("=========================Welcome to the File System =========================")
    option = input("Here are your options:\n--> Press S to upload files\n--> Press R to retrieve files")
    if option == "S" or option == "s":
        s.send("S".encode('utf-8'))

        file_name = input("Please input the file name\n>>>")
        name = input("What would you like it to be saved as?\n>>>")

        s.send(name.encode('utf-8'))
        with open(file_name,'rb') as f:
            s.sendall(f.read())
        print("File has been sent to the server")
        main()

    elif option == "R" or option == "r":
        s.send("R".encode('utf-8'))
        filename = input("What is the filename you wish to recieve\n>>>")
        s.send(filename.encode('utf-8'))

        print ("File is comming ....")
        f = open(filename,'wb')      #open that file or create one
        l = s.recv(1024)         #now recieves the contents of the file
        while (l):
            print ("Receiving...File Data")
            f.write(l)            #save input to file
            l = s.recv(1024)
        print("The file",filename,"has been succesfully saved to your computer")
        f.close()
while True:
    check = input("Do you already have an account? Y/N \n ")

    if check == "Y" or check == "y":
        login()
        break

    elif check == "N" or check == "n":
        register()
        break
    else:
        print("pleae enter either Y or N")
```

Please look at the Filesystem() in the client file. I think it is receiving the second wave of bytes when getting files that is the problem

an was error is either broken pipe which I fixed.
But now the actually receiving file loop doesn't go through and stops getting the file bytes. I believe this is my error. I am confused however since my code is pretty much identical to sending the file to the server which has no complications.

Comment: I shall update now

Answer (score 0):

> But now the actually receiving file loop doesn't go through and stops getting the file bytes. I believe this is my error.

You are right. The client gets no indication that there aren't more file contents to come, and thus keeps on waiting in `recv` forever. To rectify this, you can let the server shut down the connection when the file has been sent, or, if you want the connection to be kept, inform the client about when it has to stop receiving, e. g. by sending it the file length beforehand.